# Send JavaScript object to web server call via jQuery - what is the correct way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, stringify

I'm trying to send JSON data to my web server via jQuery and I'm running into an error.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'context' in {"id":45,"isRead":true}

code I am testing:

```
var obj = {};
obj.id = 45;
obj.isRead = true;
var data = JSON.stringify(obj);
var url = "/notification/read"
$.ajax(url, data, 'application/json', function() {
    // code remove notification from the DOM
    });
});
```

Is there a better or more correct way to do this? Not sure if I'm getting the params right on the $.ajax call either.

**UPDATE**
code I got to work

```
var obj = {
    id: 45,
    isRead: true
};
var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
var url = "/notification/read"
$.ajax({ url: url, 
         type:'POST', 
         contentType: 'application/json', 
         data: json, 
         success: function(data, textStatus) {
            // do stuff
         }
});
```

My server was expecting JSON data POSTed as application/json. So was I wrong in thinking I needed all these variables? without these it was sent as a GET and was application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Without the stringify it also didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing too many arguments to the ajax function: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Also, the `JSON.stringify` call is not necessary, jQuery will take care of that for you.

```
var obj = {
  'id':45,
  'isRead':true
};
$.ajax({
  url: "/notification/read",
  data: obj,
  success: function(data, textStatus){
    /* code here */
  }
});
```

Comment: what about type:'POST' - not needed?

Comment: seems like it is POSTing but Firefox shows I'm sending id=45&isRead=true as application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: actually it was a GET before I added type:'POST' ... weird why am I having to set extra params and you do not?

Comment: GET is the default. If you want the data POSTed (you did not specify), you'd have to specify that argument.  Check out the document page I linked to... it explains what the default for every option is. If you want something other than the default, you have to supply the option to override the default.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't worry overmuch about the content type, unless it is important to your backend code.  If your server is running PHP, then it really doesn't care about the content mime type - the data will be in $_POST or $_GET regardless.

Comment: Running Grails. Because of how the serialization stuff works, it cares. And a mobile is hitting the same API with JSON packets.

Comment: So are many PHP developers not using the built-in JSON serialization stuff to rehydrate a PHP class with the POSTed JSON from a web call?

Comment: I couldn't presume to speak for *many* PHP developers, but I can say that I have not found utility for the pattern in the work that I do.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax(url, obj);
```

You need to send an object as second param

{success: success, data: data}

Comment: what does "call back should be params" mean? do I put data in square brackets? or does that mean optional?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is here:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

You have to pass parameters as one object, not multiple ones